# HAML Forms being weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

```
-form_tag(search_path, :method => :get)
  = label_tag("Place")
  = text_field_tag("place", nil, :id => "place")
  = text_field_tag("near", nil, :id => "near")
  = submit_tag("Search", :id => "search", :name => "search", :class => "form_submit", :disabled => false, :disable_with => "Please wait...")
```

I have the code above and it returns the following error:

```
/app/app/views/venues/main.haml:7: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
```

My application template is as follows:

```
%html
  %head
    %title
      WhosHere
    = stylesheet_link_tag :all
    = javascript_include_tag 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'
    = csrf_meta_tag
  %body
    = yield
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you should have a "do" at the end of your form_tag, so that the system knows you want to pass a block to the form_tag?

```
- form_tag(search_path, :method => :get) do
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked perfectly.